# saves as and Print dialog doesn't seem to work together in php

Tags: php, http-headers

I have a products page list and i am exporting it to a word document and also allowing user to print the document `window.print`... I click `ExportToWord` button `saves as` dialog opens and i canceled it... Next when i click print button the print dialog appears for a second and minmizes and the `Saves as` dialog appears containing the word document...

For word:

```
else if($btn_value == 'word')
        {
            $nam = 'StudentSeatAllot';
            $this->load->library('table');
            $getCollege = $this->adminmodel->getUserCollege();
            $data['viewseatdet']=$this->adminmodel->seatallotreport($college);
            $this->table->set_heading('Degree','Department','Batch',
            'Category','Seatsalloted');
            $out =  $this->table->generate($data['viewseatdet']); 

            //header("Content-type: application/x-ms-download");
            //header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$cur_date.doc");
            header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control:  must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$nam.doc");
            $collegeName = $getCollege[2];
        $collegeAddr1 = $getCollege[5].', '.$getCollege[6].' - '.$getCollege[7];
            $collegeAddr2 = $getCollege[10].', '.$getCollege[8];
            echo '<b><center>'.strtoupper($collegeName).'</b>';
            echo '<br><b>'.strtoupper($collegeAddr1);
            echo '<br><b>'.strtoupper($collegeAddr2).'</center>';
            echo '<br><br>';
            echo 'S E A T  A L L O T - D E T A I L S<br><br>';
            print_r($out);
        }
```

For print i am using javascript:

```
function tablePrint()
{

var display_setting="toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,menubar=no,";
display_setting+="scrollbars=yes,,status=no,width=750, height=600, left=100, top=25";

var content_innerhtml = document.getElementById("tbl_display").innerHTML;
var document_print=window.open("","",display_setting);
document_print.document.open();
document_print.document.write('<html><head><title>Campus Unified</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url()?>stylesheets/stylesheet.css" /> </head>');
document_print.document.write('<body onLoad="self.print();" >');
document_print.document.write('<center><strong>');
document_print.document.write(content_innerhtml);
document_print.document.write('</strong></center>');
document_print.document.write('</body></html>');
document_print.document.close();

}
```

![alt text][1]

**Second EDIT:**
My print button,

```
<button type="submit" class="print" name="print" value="print" onfocus="this.blur();" 
    onclick="tablePrint();">
```

and `content_innerhtml`

```
<div id="tbl_display" style="display:none" >
<? if(isset($viewseatdet_print)) { ?>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="right" style="padding-right:5px"  class="table_label">Date : <?= date('d-m-Y') ?></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" class="table_label" align="center">
<? if(isset($_SESSION['empCollege'])) { $userCollege = $_SESSION['empCollege'];
        echo strtoupper($userCollege[2]).'<br>'.strtoupper($userCollege[5]);
        if(!empty($userCollege[6])){ echo ', '.$userCollege[6]; }
        if(!empty($userCollege[7])){ echo ' - '.$userCollege[7]; }
        if( (sizeof($userCollege))==11)
        { echo '<br>'.strtoupper($userCollege[9]).', '.strtoupper($userCollege[8]); }

    }?>
</td></tr>
</table>

<table ><tr height="10px"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
<div style="padding-left:4px" class="table_label_header" align="center">
        S E A T S - A L L O T M E N T
</div>
<table width="500px" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="1" >
    <tr>

            <td style="width:10%" class="grid_header" align="center">Degree</td>
            <td style="width:15%" class="grid_header" align="center">Department</td>
            <td style="width:15%" class="grid_header" align="center">Category</td>
            <td style="width:10%" class="grid_header" align="center">Seatsalloted</td>
    </tr>
    <? if(empty($viewseatdet_print))
 { echo '<tr><td colspan=2>no record found !</td></tr>'; } ?>
    <?  foreach($viewseatdet_print as $row) {  ?>

    <tr>
             <td style="width:10%" class="table_label" align="center"><?= $row['dDegreeName']?></td>
            <td style="width:15%" class="table_label" align="center"><?= $row['dDepartmentName']?></td>
            <td style="width:15%" class="table_label" align="center"><?= $row['dCategory']?></td>
            <td style="width:15%" class="table_label" align="center"><?= $row['dSeatsAllot']?></td>

    </tr>
    <? } ?>

</table>

<? } ?>

</div>
```

**Word HTML:**

```
<button type="submit" class="word" name="word" value="word" onfocus="this.blur();" 
    onclick="return getButtonType('word');">
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What kind of `exportToWord` function are you talking about? What is the exact problem? Can you show some code?

Comment: @chandru what do you want to achieve? Do you want to print the Word document?

Comment: @Pekka not the word document but the table iterated with my result array...

Comment: @chandru what does `content_innerhtml` contain?

Comment: @chandru what **HTML Code** does `content_innerhtml` contain? :)

Comment: And you are sure your print button is not simply wrongly linked? Can you show the HTML code for that, too?

Comment: @chandru can you show the neughbouring HTML from the "Export to Word" button as well?

Comment: @chandru no, I meant the full HTML block. But never mind, @DrColossos has already said what I suspect, too.

Comment: +1 just because this is a very novel way of "exporting" to Word. I'll be sure to use this when I need to "generate" Excel spreadsheets. Just curious though--is the save dialog created by the browser or Word? Because if it's by the browser, I would expect the file contents to actually remain HTML. Have you tried opening up one of the `.doc` files you exported to see if it contained HTML still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume there is a form around your posted button that gets called when you click the button. This wouls explain, why the 2 things happen, that you described

```
<button type="submit" [...] onclick="tablePrint(); return false; ">
```

The `return false` disables the submit action, that is attached to the button.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was on about when asking to see the full HTML.